# What's Wrong With My Lambda Expression?

Tags: c#, .net, list, lambda

I'm trying to write a simple Lambda expression in C#:

```
int numElements = 3;
string[]firstnames = {"Dave", "Jim", "Rob"};
string[]lastnames = {"Davidson", "Jameson", "Robertson"};

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

for(int i = 0 ; i < numElements; i++)
{
    people.Add(new Person { FirstName = firstnames[i], LastName = lastnames[i] });                
}

bool test = people.Contains(p => p.FirstName == "Bob");
```

My understanding of Lambda expressions and how they work is still a little shady and I miffed as to why this will not work...I'm trying to find out if a list contains a name...

Comment: Do you need people.Any(....) - this is the LINQ operator that takes a lamba.  On IEnumerable .Contains doesn't take a lamba as a parameter.

Comment: `"Rob" != "Bob"`, so `test` should end up being `false` (once you use `Any`, as James suggested). And `numElements` should equal 3, not 10.

Comment: @DaveShaw what's a `GenericList<T>` ??

Comment: why you are looping 10 iterations while you have only 3 elements in string[]

Comment: I'm tempted to change this question to "What's right with  my lamba exception". Bob == Rob? numElements = 10??

Comment: -1, since you're not stating the problem.

Comment: @AakashM - I only formatted the Question, I didn't asked it :).

Comment: Sorry guys I copied numElements = 10 when it isn't, it reads numElements = 3 in my code.

Comment: @James Gaunt - you got it, cheers

Comment: @DaveShaw I think [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9380262/revisions) introduced a typo is all

Comment: @AakashM Looks like a Ninja Edit - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45499/162486

Comment: @DaveShaw I am enlightened :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
bool test = people.Any(p => p.FirstName == "Bob");
```

Or are you mixing Rob and Bob?

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is not lambdas but instead the boundaries of the `for` loop.  The arrays you defined have a length of 3 but `numElements` is defined to have a value of `10`.  This means you will get an exception for an illegal array index on the 4th iteration of the loop.  Try the following

```
int numElements = 3;
```

Or more simply remove the `numElements` variable and instead iterate to the length of the `firstnames` array

```
for (int i = 0; i < firstnames.length; i++) {
  ...
}
```

**EDIT**

OP indicated that the `numElements` originally posted was a typo.  Other possible sources of error in the code

- Use `"Rob"` instead of `"Bob"` if you want to find a matching element
- The `Contains` method on `GenericList<T>` needs to have a compatible delegate signature.  `Func<T, bool>` for example

Comment: Sorry :s That was my mistake when copying the code and is not the issue.

Comment: @user559142 then what problem are you hitting?

Comment: actually he is asking about lambda this `people.Contains(p => p.FirstName == "Bob")` will also not compiled.

Comment: The problem was it couldn't convert lambda type as it is not a delegate...not sure why but Any() works instead of Contains()...

Comment: @user559142 what is the type of `GenericList<T>`?

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure you are linking the System.Linq namemespace, i.e.

   ```
   using System.Linq;
   ```
2. You are using the Contains method. This method expects a Person and will use an equality comparison to determine if your collection already contains it. In the default case, the equality comparison defaults to reference comparison so it will never contain it, but that's another topic.
3. To achieve your goal, use the Any method. This will tell you if ANY of the elements in your collection conform to a condition.

   ```
   people.Any(p => p.FirstName == "BoB");
   ```

You may want to read about [the extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx) First and FirstOrDefault and Where as they would also solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't set `numElements` to the correct value ( you set it to 10, but your arrays only have 3 values) - furthermore you don't even need it, just use a collection initializer instead of those separate string arrays:

```
GenericList<Person> people = new GenericList<Person>()
{
    new Person { FirstName = "Dave", LastName = "Davidson" },
    new Person { FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Jameson" }
    new Person { FirstName = "Rob", LastName = "Robertson" }
}
```

Now assuming your `GenericList<T>` class implements `IEnumerable<T>` you can use `Any()` to do your test:

```
bool test = people.Any(p => p.FirstName == "Bob");
```

Answer (score 0):

what your real problem with this lambdas ?

If because you have test false then that's true you don't have "Bob" in firstName

```
bool test = people.Contains(p => p.FirstName == "Bob");
```

and

```
string[]firstnames = {"Dave", "Jim", "Rob"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems here.

One: `GenericList` is not a type.  You were probably looking for the generic type `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`.

Two:  `Contains` accepts a `Person` in your example, not a delegate (lambdas are a new way to write delegates as of C# 3).  One way to get what you want here would be to combine `Where` and `Count`, in the form of `bool test = people.Where(p => p.FirstName == "Bob").Count() > 0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
// We will use these things:
Predicate<Person> yourPredicate = p => p.FirstName == "Bob";
Func<Person, bool> yourPredicateFunction = p => p.FirstName == "Bob";
Person specificPerson = people[0];

// Checking existence of someone:
bool test = people.Contains(specificPerson);
bool anyBobExistsHere = people.Exists(yourPredicate);

// Accessing to a person/people:
IEnumerable<Person> allBobs = people.Where(yourPredicateFunction);
Person firstBob = people.Find(yourPredicate);
Person lastBob = people.FindLast(yourPredicate);

// Finding index of a person
int indexOfFirstBob = people.FindIndex(yourPredicate);
int indexOfLastBob = people.FindLastIndex(yourPredicate);
```

You should play with LINQ methods somewhile...

Comment: Very nice explanation of predicates! :)